# Show Message-ID for mail being written

Tags: email, mutt

Is there any way to print/predict the `Message-ID` that mutt will assign to the mail currently being composed?

It looks like it consists of a timestamp, a random string (is it?) and the `hostname` from `muttrc`, but it's unclear when this is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message identifier is generated if necessary when the envelope is prepared, *i.e.* just before `mutt` sends the email. There doesn't seem to be a way of seeing the generated identifier within `mutt` before the message is sent. If you manually specify your own identifier in the composed message, `mutt` will use that...

The generated identifier itself contains the following information (see [`mutt_gen_msgid()` in `sendlib.c`](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/blob/master/sendlib.c#L2413)), as of the current development tip:

- year;
- month;
- day in month;
- hour;
- minute;
- second;
- a single character between 'A' and 'Z';
- `mutt`'s process identifier;
- the host's FQDN.

In the version I currently have on Debian though there is indeed a [random string](https://sources.debian.org/src/mutt/1.7.2-1+deb9u3/sendlib.c/#L2183) (instead of the single character and process identifier).

In any case the identifier isn't predictable accurately!

Comment: "If you manually specify your own identifier" -> to be clear, you're talking about editing the headers (`E` by default) and adding `Message-ID: foo@bar.baz`, right? If so, I can do that whenever I need to know the ID of my message before sending it, so it fits my needs perfectly! (All I need is to write a one-liner that generates something that looks like `mutt`'s message ID :)

Comment: That's exactly it (I have `edit_hdrs` set, so I always have the headers in my editor).

Comment: NOTE: originally `1.7.1-5` Debian version was mentioned, thus I expect that the answer, but I included current master (`1.14.7`) in the upstream sources link. BTW there will be more security related fixes in `1.14.8`, see https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/commit/9da4e6e11e7037668d0ca7e8f5d6773d26e379ac